# SVN log showing empty revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

If I do an svn log command on my repo, there are 3 revisions in a row that come back as empty:

```
svn log https://url.to.trunk -r529:HEAD --xml -v
```

It comes back with a whole bunch of revisions but then:

```
<logentry revision="565"/>
<logentry revision="566"/>
<logentry revision="567"/>
```

If I look at these same revisions in TortoiseSVN by doing a "show log" it lists the files that were modified by these revisions no problem.  Where is TortoiseSVN getting the details from if not from svn log and how can I fix this? I need the log for statistical analysis.

I'm using VisualSVN as my server.

Comment: Can you add information of the versions you use: server, svn cmd client, TortoiseSVN. What is the contents of the revisions 565 - 567? Only property changes, something special that may help?

Comment: VisualSVN server, SlikSVN 1.6.17 client, TortoiseSVN 1.6.17.  Revs 565-567 include file modifications only, no prop changes at all.

Comment: What does `svn log https://url.to.repository.root -r565:567 --xml -v` show? Is it possible that those changesets were made in a different directory? I know my SVN client/server output '<log></log>' in that situation, but maybe VisualSVN/SlikSVN report it differently.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="565">
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="566">
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="567">
</logentry>
</log>

No dice :-(

Comment: Not sure if it is the same thing but I have an entry in Tortoise with no author, modification types, files or date (says '(no date)') I for one am worried this is corruption of our repository.